# PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: apache2, php, curl

I'm getting this error in my apache error log while trying to get cURL to work on PHP:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so: symbol curl_easy_pause, version CURL_OPENSSL_3 not defined in file libcurl.so.4 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
```

The file it references is there in that location and I'm trying to figure out if I've missed any dependancies while installing curl for PHP. There are no errors when I use `curl -V` on the command line.

I've tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

I've also tried removing php completely and installing it from scratch using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli
```

Then after:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

What am I missing here?

My software versions:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.2 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2014 17:17:37) 
curl 7.16.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.16.0
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post `ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl*` and `ls -l /usr/lib64/libcrypto*`?

Comment: Hi @Letizia, thanks for your reply. For both I got the following: `ls: cannot access /usr/lib64/libcrypto*: No such file or directory` and I also tried `ls -l /usr/lib/libcrypto*` and got the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems libcurl depends on libssl. could you post `ldd /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4` output?

Comment: It seems that `libcurl.so.4` isn't in the `/usr/lib` folder (I don't have a `lib64` folder). I noticed that it is in another folder name `x86_64-linux-gnu`. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/teWn1uaT

Comment: sorry, I was wrong directory. libcurl seems is not updated. Here is link to [Ubuntu packages php-curl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-curl) where you can see that depends on [libcurl3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcurl3) that currently is (7.35.0-1ubuntu2). I guess that `apt-get install openssl` command overrides libcurl, try to verify /var/log/dpkg.log in order to view which library was installed by your command.

Comment: Looking at `/var/log/dpkg.log` I found this line: `2014-06-18 11:03:11 status installed libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64 7.35.0-1ubuntu2`. There was no `libcurl3` records however.

Comment: In answer to your original question but with the correct paths in, I've uploaded the output here: http://pastebin.com/RdiM9icw

Comment: As you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcurl4-openssl-dev) libcurl4-openssl.dev depends on libcurl3. It seems a dependency problem, try `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` and let us see if solves the issue

Comment: Unfortunately it just returns with this: http://pastebin.com/WrSWcWCJ

Comment: mmmh! we need to know which packages depend on libcurl4. try to find this information in /var/log/dpkg.log or/and try `apt-cache rdepends libcurl4-openssl-dev`. Could you post `ls -l /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so` output?

Comment: Here is my output for `apt-cache rdepends libcurl4-openssl-dev`: http://pastebin.com/KubDvrgF & output for `ls -l /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so`: http://pastebin.com/CvL8egzd. The only records of libcurl4 in the log file are the installation logs I posted earlier!

Comment: So let's see: in the system are installed two versions of libcurl and according to the error message, we know that php is using libcurl4 but in the official documentation of ubuntu we find that php-curl depends on libcurl3. Another point: php runs on apache, script `/etc/init.d/apache2` that runs httpd daemon should sets the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in which are defined the directories where find shared libraries. Could you verify the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH and where are the two library: libcurl3.so and libcurl4.so?

Comment: Entering `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns nothing in the command line. Both `libcurl.so.3` & `libcurl.so.4` are in the folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Comment: try `grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH /etc/init.d/apache2` and post the output. Olso post output of `find / -name "*libcurl*" -exec ls -l {} \; -print`. Sorry for the many questions, but I do not have your own version of ubuntu :)

Comment: That's ok, I appreciate the help! `grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH /etc/init.d/apache2` posts nothing again. The `find` command outputs this: http://pastebin.com/QsvgPFbw.

Comment: okey, on ubuntu the runtime library path is defined by ld.so, and we can see the ordered list of libraries by `strings /etc/ld.so.cache` or by reading /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*. Let's see how it is and then we will try to change.

Comment: OK, the output for `strings /etc/ld.so.cache` is http://pastebin.com/j09ptFc8

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was wrong. The two library are the same, `libcurl3.so` is a symbolic link to `libcurl4.so` that point to `libcurl.so.4.3.0`. So, it doesn't matter the libraries order. I get the source code of [libcurl3 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcurl3) package and the function `curl_easy_pause` is present since 7.18.0. I begin to think that this is a bug in compilation process. I also get debian package for amd64 and I notice that the date of your file are different...

Comment: your `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 422696 Apr  1 13:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0` mine `-rw-r--r-- 1 caterina caterina 422696 apr  1 19:43 libcurl.so.4.3.0`. Could you check your repository in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list http://pastebin.com/zc2mpmMp. I did try change my source list from one generated from http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ but that was after I had installed everything - so I guess it might not have been able to fix it? Do you think I need to reinstall everything with a new source.list?

Comment: Before making a decision, try `readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 | grep curl_easy_pause` if it posts nothing or if the symbol is undefined it should means that yuor libcurl3 package is broken. Save the output of `readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4` and `readelf -s /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so` so I can see it.

Comment: My output for `readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 | grep curl_easy_pause` http://pastebin.com/xmG2B72K. Output for `readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4` http://pastebin.com/Y9s4z67B & output for `readelf -s /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so` http://pastebin.com/u9PRPE6C

Comment: I'm really frustrated, libcurl3 seems ok. try `readelf -a /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so` and post the output.

Comment: Maybe I found it! You have two libcurl.so.4: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4` that is a link to libcurl.so.4.3.0 and it seems ok, and `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4` that is a link to `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.0.0`. ld.so.cache output posted above, indicates that this library is loaded before the other. So just for a test `mkdir /tmp/saveLibcurl; sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libcurl* /tmp/saveLibcurl; service apache2 restart` and let's see if it works. If it works, we'll have to find out the right solution. At the end of the test restore file moved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - was on holiday. This seems to have fixed the errors and curl now displays in `phpinfo()`. Is this fully fixed or is there other steps we'll have to do now?

Comment: welcome back @jam6549, I figured you'd gone on holiday :) I answered your question and I have tried to summarize all of our comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your system are installed two different version of libcurl:

- `libcurl3.so` that is a symbolic link to `libcurl4.so` that point to `libcurl.so.4.3.0`

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Apr  1 13:43
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4 lrwxrwxrwx 1
>   root root 16 Apr  1 13:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 ->
>   libcurl.so.4.3.0
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 422696 Apr  1 13:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0

- a local version of libcurl.so.4 that is a link to libcurl.so.4.0.0

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jun 18 09:26 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 ->
>   libcurl.so.4.0.0
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1146079 Jun 18 09:26 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.0.0

This local library `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4` is loaded before `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4`. We can see [ld library order](http://pastebin.com/j09ptFc8) using command `strings /etc/ld.so.cache`.

As I can see in `find / -name "*libcurl*" -exec ls -l {} \; -print` [output](http://pastebin.com/QsvgPFbw), you installed a source package of **libcurl-7.16.0** in `/usr/local/src/curl-7.16.0/` and I guess you compiled and generated `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.0.0`.

The missing method `curl_easy_pause` is present in libcurl since **7.18.0** and that's why I got the error, your system is using `libcurl-7.16.0`.

In order to fix this issue, remove wrong libcurl and update ld.so cache:

```
     sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcurl*
     sudo ldconfig -v
```

I suggest to remove `/usr/local/src/curl-7.16.0` directory to prevent any other kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time & help @Letizia! Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks to you, trying to help, I learned a lot of things I did not know